# Yarn virtual memory usage

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hadoop-yarn

I am running an oozie workflow consisting of a shell action that runs this script.

```
java -classpath my.jar my.package.Main
```

The shell action configuration looks like this

```
<action name="run-test-script">
  <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <exec>run.sh</exec>
    <file>${wf:conf("oozie.wf.application.path")}/run.sh</file>
  </shell>
  <ok to="end"/>
  <error to="report_failure"/>
</action>
```

In Yarn (Cloudera Mgr GUI) I have the following set

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4GiB
```

When I run this, it fails and in Yarn I get the following error message:

Container [pid=8340,containerID=container_1397556756420_5519_01_000002] is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 327.6 MB of 4 GB physical memory used; 33.2 GB of 8.4 GB virtual memory used. Killing container. Dump of the process-tree for container_1397556756420_5519_01_000002 : |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE |- 8467 8466 8340 8340 (java) 21 2 34039132160 15889 java -classpath my-jar.jar my.package.Main |- 8466 8340 8340 8340 (run.sh) 0 0 108654592 304 /bin/bash ./run.sh |- 8340 31401 8340 8340 (java) 396 21 1476808704 67682 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx825955249 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data24/yarn/nm/usercache/thomas.larsson/appcache/application_1397556756420_5519/container_1397556756420_5519_01_000002/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.container.log.dir=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/container/application_1397556756420_5519/container_1397556756420_5519_01_000002 -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 10.4.4.108 52668 attempt_1397556756420_5519_m_000000_0 2 Container killed on request. Exit code is 143

My question is, why is this task trying to allocate 33.2 Gb of virtual memory?

Update: Sorry, I forgot to post the java class...

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Running Main.");
    Thread.sleep(1000*60);
    System.out.println("Completed.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I got the same problem. Have you figured out it yet?

Answer (score 1):

the map mb size you're looking at is irrelevant since you're not starting a map/reduce
check all the memory related YARN settings, it might be that your minimal allocation for containers is too high

Comment: Hmm, well I have yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=1024 and yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio=2.1 so I don't see how that's the source.

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because you must've enabled vmem check. And it's crossing the virtual memory limit.

Current usage: 327.6 MB of 4 GB physical memory used; 33.2 GB of 8.4 GB